# How should I structure and access a table of data so that I can compare subsets easily in Python 3.5?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

1. Is there a faster, more pythonic way of doing this?
2. What is
   generating this warning `UserWarning: Boolean Series key will be
   reindexed to match DataFrame index. "DataFrame index.", UserWarning`
   and should I be concerned with it?

I have a csv file with 3 columns: org, month, person.

```
| org |    month   | person |
| --- | ---------- | ------ |
|   1 | 2014-01-01 |    100 |
|   1 | 2014-01-01 |    200 |
|   1 | 2014-01-02 |    200 |
|   2 | 2014-01-01 |    300 |
```

Which I've read into a `pandas.core.frame.DataFrame` with:

```
data = pd.read_csv('data_base.csv', names=['month', 'org', 'person'], skiprows=1)
```

The end goal is to compare the intersection of persons between 2 consecutive periods with the set of persons in the first period.

```
org: 1, month: 2014-01-01, count(intersection((100, 200), 200)) / len(set(100, 200)) == 0.5
```

Edit: I got it to work with:

```
import pandas as pd
import sys

data = pd.read_csv('data_base.csv', names=['month', 'org', 'person'], skiprows=1)
data.sort_values(by=['org', 'month', 'person'])

results = {}
for _org in set(data.org):
    results[_org] = {}
    months = sorted(list(set(data[data.org == _org].month)))
    for _m1, _m2 in zip(months, months[1:]):
        _s1 = set(data[data.org == _org][data.month == _m1].person)
        _s2 = set(data[data.org == _org][data.month == _m2].person)
        results[_org][_m1] = float(len(_s1 & _s2) / len(_s1))
        print(str(_org) + '\t' + str(_m1) + '\t' + str(_m2) + '\t' + str(round(results[_org][_m1], 2)))
        sys.stdout.flush()
```

Which produces output like this:

```
UserWarning: Boolean Series key will be reindexed to match DataFrame index. "DataFrame index.", UserWarning
5640    2014-01-01  2014-02-01  0.75
5640    2014-02-01  2014-03-01  0.36
5640    2014-03-01  2014-04-01  0.6
...
```

But it's **really slow and kind of ugly**...at the current rate my back-of-the-envelope-calculation estimates it at about 22 hours for a 2-year batch of data.

Comment: Pandas is great for full operations, not for slicing. The time to access a single element is on the order of 10-100 microseconds, a full 1000x what you would get for dictionary lookups (under 50 ns).

The tradeoff is pandas is great for full-dataframe or column-wise calculations with large data: the long start times are nicely traded off with the extremely fast, vectorized calculations.

Here, you are effectively doing element-by-element calculations and converting from Pandas types, meaning Pandas, although excellent, is not the right library for this task.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Admittedly, I have never used Pandas, so this may not be idiomatic. This just uses basic Python structures.

```
import collections
org_month_dict = collections.defaultdict(set)

# put the data into a simple, indexed data structure
for index, row in data.iterrows():
    org_month_dict[row['org'], row['month']].add(row['person'])

orgs = set(data.org)
months = sorted(set(data.months))
for org in orgs:
    for mindex in range(len(months)-1):
        m1 = months[mindex]
        m2 = months[mindex+1]
        print org_month_dict[org, m2] & org_month_dict[org, m1] # persons in common between month 1 and 2
```

This creates a "cached" lookup table in `org_month_dict` which is indexed by organization and month, saving you from doing the expensive `data[data.org == _org][data.month == _m1]` lookup in your inner loop. It should run significantly faster than your original code.

Comment: He shouldn't be using Pandas here anyway (see my comment above in a second), so this is an excellent answer using the correct approach.

Comment: Thanks for the info on Pandas' shortcomings with slicing speed. I looked up how to read csv files into Python and the examples used Pandas' read_csv function, so that's how I went down that route.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't necessarily dismiss pandas here.  It depends on a few things.  I don't think pandas will be a really compact way to store your data, although it has automatic compression and sparse storage options which largely mitigate this.  I'd expect the speed to be quite reasonable, but you'd really have to test it on your data to say for sure.

It does offer (in my opinion) a more convenient way to store your data and also offers convenient ways of dealing with dates.  And when you are done, you can output results in tabular form.

First, I'm going to expand the data a little bit to better demonstrate the issues.

```
    org       month  person
0     1  2014-01-01     100
1     1  2014-01-01     200
2     1  2014-01-02     200
3     1  2014-01-03     300
4     1  2014-01-03     100
5     1  2014-01-04     200
6     1  2014-01-04     100
7     1  2014-01-04     300
8     2  2014-01-01     100
9     2  2014-01-01     200
10    2  2014-01-02     300
11    2  2014-01-02     400
12    2  2014-01-03     100
13    2  2014-01-04     200
14    2  2014-01-04     100
```

Then, you could do something like this:

```
df['one'] = 1
df = df.set_index(['org','month','person']).unstack('person')
numer = ((df==df.shift(-1)) & (df.notnull())).sum(axis=1)
denom = df.notnull().sum(axis=1)

df['numer'] = numer
df['denom'] = denom
df['ratio'] = numer / denom

               one             numer denom     ratio
person         100 200 300 400                      
org month                                           
1   2014-01-01   1   1 NaN NaN     1     2  0.500000
    2014-01-02 NaN   1 NaN NaN     0     1  0.000000
    2014-01-03   1 NaN   1 NaN     2     2  1.000000
    2014-01-04   1   1   1 NaN     2     3  0.666667
2   2014-01-01   1   1 NaN NaN     0     2  0.000000
    2014-01-02 NaN NaN   1   1     0     2  0.000000
    2014-01-03   1 NaN NaN NaN     1     1  1.000000
    2014-01-04   1   1 NaN NaN     0     2  0.000000
```

I'm ignoring some details here, like the breakpoint between org 1 and org 2 but you could add a groupby to deal with this.  Similarly, you may want to add code to handle days with no person present and there are ways to deal with that also.

Comment: Can you explain the `(df==df.shift(-1))` line?

Comment: That's a boolean showing which cells match the cell above.  Just take the `numer` line and print out the individual pieces of it to get a better idea of what it's doing.